# How do I fix this? It crashes

Tags: c, switch-statement

The individual programs run by themselves, but comes up with invalid arguments after the program runs
Why is this happening. You can even help by showing me where I can read up on this situation. THanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void ld_file(); //declaring functions
void mirror_file();

int main()//setting up the menu
{
    int choice;
    printf("Choose a digit between 0 and 5\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 0:{ld_file();
        break;}

        case 1:{mirror_file();
        break;}
    }
}
// Individual Programs
//**************Load file***********//
void ld_file()
{
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *in;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    gets(file_name);
    in = fopen(file_name,"r"); // reading file
    if( in == NULL )
       {
           perror("File not found.\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Contents of %s are:\n", file_name);

        while( ( ch = fgetc(in) ) != EOF )
            printf("%c",ch);
        fclose(in);
        return;
}

//*****************Copy File**************//
void mirror_file()
{
   char ch, orig_file[20], new_file[20];
   FILE *orig, *neo;

   printf("Enter name of file to copy\n");
   gets(orig_file);

   orig = fopen(orig_file, "r");

   if( orig == NULL )
   {
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("Enter name of new file\n");
   gets(new_file);

   neo = fopen(new_file, "w+");
   fprintf(neo,"620048876, 23/4/14\n");

   if( neo == NULL )
   {
      fclose(orig);
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while( ( ch = fgetc(orig) ) != EOF )
      fputc(ch, neo);

   printf("File copied successfully.\n");

   fclose(orig);
   fclose(neo);

   return;
}

//*********Encrypt File*******//
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to choice, rather than choice itself to scanf, i.e. `scanf ("%d", &choice);`

Comment: Also, since `choice` is `int`, you should use `case 0` instead of `case '0'`

Comment: `fprintf(neo,"620048876, 23/4/14\n");` should be after `if(neo == NULL )`

Comment: `scanf("%d", choice);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &choice);` and `char ch` --> `int ch`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY... it runs now but when I select the number that corresponds to the program, the program runs without actually doing what it should. I made the programs by themselves first so I know it should work

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d", choice);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Btw your switch case should **check for characters**. `0` is the null character, and it is not what you get when typing `0` on the keyboard.

```
switch (choice)
{
    case '0':{ld_file();
    break;}

    case '1':{mirror_file();
    break;}

    case 'a': ; //etc..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should paas the address of choice in scanf :

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

And Your switch code should be like below:

```
switch (choice)
    {
        case 0:{ld_file();
        break;}

        case 1:{mirror_file();
        break;}
    }
```